# Semisimple implies complete reducibility

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, ideals, lie-algebras

Why does a semisimple Lie algebra imply complete reducibility?

I have that a semisimple Lie algebra is a Lie algebra with no non-zero solvable ideals. Complete reducibility means that every invariant subspace of a representation has a complement.

But I do not understand why the Lie algebra must be semisimple to have complete reducibility.

Comment: That is not correct. The correct statement is that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a (finite-dimensional) semisimple Lie algebra then its *finite-dimensional* representations are completely reducible. Its infinite-dimensional representations need not have this property. Anyway, there are several ways to prove this, none of which are particularly easy (it isn't just a direct proof from the definition or it would work in the infinite-dimensional case). Any textbook on Lie theory will do it one way or another.

Comment: Even a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra need not have completely reducible f.d. representations in general. There are counterexamples over fields of prime characteristic. The reason is that Whitehead's lemma fails in characteristic $p>0$.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I meant over a field of characteristic zero, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main algebraic reason behind Weyl's theorem on complete reducibility is *Whitehead's first lemma*, i.e., that the first Lie algebra cohomology with finite-dimensional modules as coefficients vanishes for finite-dimensional *semisimple* Lie algebras of characteristic zero.

It is easy to see that we need *semisimple* for this result. A first step is to see that a semisimple Lie algebra has only inner derivations, under the above assumptions.

The property of being semisimple is very important also for the classification theory and for the representation theory of Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

As Qiaochu points out, this only holds in the finite dimensional case and the proof is somewhat involved.  I think it's better to give a reference here than try and repeat a long argument you could find in any text on the subject:

- See Chapter II.6 of Humphrey's book *Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory*.  In particular, Theorem 6.3 of that section is what you're looking for.